# Read csv content without loop

Tags: python, django, csv

I am trying to attach a csv file to message and send away.

```
# i generated the file 'stats.csv' and it is there.
f = open('stats.csv')
filedata = csv.reader(f)
msg.attach('stats.csv', filedata, 'text/csv')
```

but the attachment which i am getting per email has ony this line:

```
<_csv.reader object at 0x1b1e750>
```

If I try

```
f = open('stats.csv')
msg.attach('stats.csv', f, 'text/csv')
```

i am getting

```
<open file 'stats.csv', mode 'r' at 0x1a76030>
```

inside attachment.

I just want to send csv file as attachment which shows the content of csv file. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think this function `msg.attach` transforms `filedata` into a string, and that's why it prints that. Just like when you use `print filedata`. What class is `msg` from?

Comment: If you are trying to send the `csv` file as an attachment , I think you don't even need to use `csv.reader`. You could treat it like any other file.

Comment: @t.pimentel ``msg`` is from ``EmailMultiAlternatives``

Comment: @g4ur4v if send just the ``f``, i am getting ``<open file 'stats.csv', mode 'r' at 0x1a76030>`` inside attachment

Comment: @t.pimentel ``attach`` should treat it as a file since I am giving ``text/csv``, and not to convert to string. shouldnot it?

Comment: I think `text/csv` says its text, correspondent to csv file. The same `text/html`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

```
f = open('stats.csv', 'r+')
filedata = f.read()
msg.attach_alternative(filedata, "text/csv")
```

Comment: would be nice, but i am creating the file on the fly

Comment: save it in temporary location and use `msg.attach_file` .

Comment: too much overhead by saving and again reading in. the file is already there, the problem is how to make attachment show its content.

Answer (score 0):

i solved by doing this:

```
response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
writer = csv.writer(response)
msg.attach('stats.csv', response, 'text/csv')
```